# QSettings - how to honour when user deletes file?

Tags: python, pyside2

I am trying to figure out the simplest use of [QSettings](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide2/QtCore/QSettings.html#PySide2.QtCore.PySide2.QtCore.QSettings.setValue) with this snippet:

```
from PySide2 import QtCore
settings = QtCore.QSettings("TestCompany", "TestApp")
settings.setValue('testValue', 100)
```

On OSX this eventually writes a plist to:

```
/Users/frank/Library/Preferences/com.testcompany.TestApp.plist
```

As per the [docs](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide2/QtCore/QSettings.html#PySide2.QtCore.PySide2.QtCore.QSettings.setValue) the changes may not be written immediately for efficiency reasons.

Once I see the plist file though, I assumed I could delete it, so that next time I launch my application an attempt to return a value from a new settings instance would return None.

However, even when I delete the plist file and close my python interpreter, then re-open it and construct a new [QSettings](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide2/QtCore/QSettings.html#PySide2.QtCore.PySide2.QtCore.QSettings.setValue) instance, it still somehow manages to retrieve the previously set value for "testValue".

How can I manage this so that when a user deletes the settings file and restarts the QT application, they get a clean slate rather than old values?

Do I have to manually check for the existence of the plist file and use [clear()](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide2/QtCore/QSettings.html#PySide2.QtCore.PySide2.QtCore.QSettings.clear) to flush out any existing values in memory or is there a better way to guarantee a clean slate when the file is deleted and the app restarted?

Comment: No. Something is wrong with the scenario you mentioned.

Comment: Since QSettings is using the CFPreferences API on macOs by default, probably the system is caching the values for you somewhere else. The qt docs do not clearly states this, but you could try to store the settings using the INI format instead of the native one to see if this changes the default behavior. I'm not sure anyway... just making an educated guess :)

Comment: Thanks guys. I had to revert to using the ini format and an explicit path in order to get the behaviour I want. I had hoped to still be able to use the os default locations.
I think you are right Gabriella, there is more system caching happening than one would expect, even when using sync() the file is not necessarily created on disk.

Answer (score 1):

I know the post is a bit old but I was having the same problem and found that yes OSX will eventually write down your settings to:

```
/Users/frank/Library/Preferences/com.testcompany.TestApp.plist
```

But this does not seem to happen immediately, when you save your settings.

It caches your settings - and inorder to reset you would have to issue the following command in the MAC OSX terminal :

```
$ defaults delete com.testcompany.TestApp
```

Hope this helps anybody who ends up here, henceforth.